# IPv6 Bind Fail Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6

There is some weird issue going on with my system in which IPv6 bind is failing for IP ending with "128" and passing for all other IPs. This is not the link local or any other conflicting address. 
I have read many posts regarding bind fail for IPv6 but most of the issues are related with people using wrong IPs or conflicting IPs.

IP Fail --> fc12:849:1009:71:46:128

IP Pass --> fc12:849:1009:71:46:129/30/27

The error message I am getting is **Cannot assign requested address** and ifconfig output shows that the IP has been asseigned to eth0 successfully.

**Edit:** Sorry for not providing the complete information but the complete IP address is "2002:914:fc12:849:1009:71:46:128". So it has eight sections as required according to IPv6 protocol.

Comment: We really need to see [your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also: make sure that the addresses are out of `tentative` state when you try to bind to them.

Comment: What do you mean by "tentative" state?

Comment: When an IPv6 address is configured on an interface the OS usually first does DAD (Duplicate Address Detection) to make sure that the address is not already in use. While the OS is doing that the address is tentative. You can see this in the output of `ip -6 addr`. For example: `inet6 2001:db8::1/64 scope global tentative`

Comment: But first start to use valid IPv6 addresses, because that is your real problem!

Comment: Tried to assign the IP address again and looks like DAD is failing for this address.

4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2002:914:fc12:849:1009:71:46:128/64 scope **global tentative dadfailed**
I will be looking further why this is happening and would be updating with a reason. Thanks @SanderSteffann

Comment: You are using 6to4 addresses on IBM IPv4 space. Are you sure those are yours?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be able to bind to any of these addresses. IPv6 addresses have 8 sections separated by colons. If there are less than 8 sections, there have to be a double colon between two of the sections.

For example the following address would be a valid IPv6 address:

fc12:849::1009:71:46:128

Comment: What are the commands you are using when you get the error message you provided? How is your network configured in general?
Also I wonder whether Stackoverflow is really the right place to ask this question. http://unix.stackexchange.com might be the better place for this question.